# Javascript Closure Inheritance: is it possible to have Functions with the same Name in the Base Object and the Derived One?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, closures

I have a simple closure-based inheritance:

```
function BaseObject(a) {
    this.a = a;

    this.MyFunction = function() {
        // ...
    }
}

function DerivedObject(a, b) {
    BaseObject.call(this, a)
    this.b = b;

    this.MyFunction = function() {
        // ...
    }
}

var instance = new DerivedObject(someValue, someOtherValue);
instance.MyFunction();
```

This will call the version of MyFunction defined in DerivedObject. Is there a way to set up the base/derived objects so that I can decide which one to call?

Comment: Why would you want to be able to choose?  That usually goes against the pattern of why you'd want to do this in the first place.  It's sometimes useful to call the base method from the derived one, but not externally?

Comment: I want to be able to do this from the Base Object - executing the Derived one after the Base one. Or even in the Derived one, perhaps sometimes I want to run it, sometimes not. I can already achieve this by using different names in both objects, but I was wondering if there was a more seamless way to achieve this.

Comment: I you want to be able to choose which method to call, don't give them the same name?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to call `BaseObject`'s `MyFunction` from your `DerivedObject`s, just keep a reference to the function before overwriting it with your own:

```
function DerivedObject(a, b) {
    BaseObject.call(this, a)
    this.b = b;

    const baseMyFunction = this.myFunction;
    this.myFunction = function() {
        // call parent
        const res = baseMyFunction.call(this);
        // …
    };
}
```